# validate split button dropdowns bootstrap with html required attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to validate (i.e. make required) the bootstrap split button dropdowns using html required attribute?

Below is bootstrap split button dropdowns code:

```
<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As there is no direct select html tag and buttons can't be required. So, how to add required to the bootstrap split button dropdowns.

Thanks

Comment: *"there is no direct select html tag"* so add something like this. With a bit of JS it's quite easy to bind select with required to split button and make them share validation state.

Comment: okay. You meant that I add a "select" tag that is hidden and when user selects any option, jquery/javascript will help to update the select tag option, dynamically through JS. Right?

Comment: Yes, something like this should be easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can set value on change of split button as below:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
    $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
});
```

You can get selected value of split button by following line

```
$(".btn:first-child").val();
```

and validate it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Is This a sultion tha could work 4 you, just something that trugh togheter under 5 minutes, you need to ad some css to fix the button sice difrence.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="http://google.com" type="button">Action</a> <button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"><span class="caret"></span> <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your responses.

I have achieved it using HTML and jquery code. My scenario here was that; If the textbox is empty then the SELECT (split dropdown) become mandatory and vice versa.

I added `<select id="splitBtnBreakFree" style="display:none"></select>` and then in my jquery code based on my scenario, i write below code as:

```
$("#splitBtnBreakFree").removeAttr("required");
if($("#breakFeeAmount").val() != "" && $("#btnActionOfFessValue").text() == "Select an option"){
   $("#splitBtnBreakFree").prop("required",true);
}
```

I hope this may help someone.

Regards & Thanks,

Owais